# Find optimal combinations of two columns based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

So, my dataframe looks like this

---

```
index       Client  Manager   Score
0             1        1      0.89
1             1        2      0.78
2             1        3      0.65
3             2        1      0.91
4             2        2      0.77
5             2        3      0.97
6             3        1      0.35
7             3        2      0.61
8             3        3      0.81
9             4        1      0.69
10            4        2      0.22
11            4        3      0.93
12            5        1      0.78
13            5        2      0.55
14            5        3      0.44
15            6        1      0.64
16            6        2      0.99
17            6        3      0.22
```

---

My expected output looks like this

---

```
index  Client   Manager  Score
0        1        1      0.89
1        2        3      0.97
2        3        2      0.61
3        4        3      0.93
4        5        1      0.78
5        6        2      0.99
```

---

We have 3 managers and 6 clients. I want each manager to have 2 clients based on highest Score. Each manager should have only unique client, so that if one client is good for two managers, we need to take second best score and so on. May I have your suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a problem of integer programming if you want to maximize the score of both.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.drop("index", axis=1)
df = df.sort_values("Score").iloc[::-1,:]
df

selected_client = []
selected_manager = []
selected_df = []
iter_rows = df.iterrows()

for i,d in iter_rows:
    client = int(d.to_frame().loc[["Client"],[i]].values[0][0])
    manager = int(d.to_frame().loc[["Manager"],[i]].values[0][0]) 

    if client not in selected_client and selected_manager.count(manager) != 2:            
        selected_client.append(client)
        selected_manager.append(manager)

        selected_df.append(d)

result = pd.concat(selected_df, axis=1, sort=False)
print(result.T)
```

Comment: Would you explain your solution after the sorting section? Did you define/see elements of the `Client` and `Manager` columns within DataFrame integers`1` or string `'1'`? it seems you followed the comment of @Corralien ?

Comment: you try code output ? @Mario

Comment: I sorted by score and then I got the high scores each manager got from two different clients it's not hard to understand
Isn't the goal to achieve the highest overall score for customer satisfaction?

Comment: I reproduced the data and applied your solution, and got the output.  I was wondering about explanation of used _for-loop_ and following _if-cluase_ to achieve the expected result for better understanding. I don't think elaborating on that is a big deal and based on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), kindly *"a good answer should include both documented code and a short explanation about the algorithm/logic of the solution."*. Personally, I think there could be an elegant way to resolve this problem by `groupby()` with the condition.

Comment: thanks for your advice then you solve it with groupby method :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.sort_values('Score',ascending = False) #sort values to prioritize high scores

d = {i:[] for i in df['Manager']} #create an empty dictionary to fill in the client/manager pairs

n = 2 #set number of clients per manager
for c,m in zip(df['Client'],df['Manager']): #iterate over client and manager pairs
    if len(d.get(m))<n and c not in [c2 for i in d.values() for c2,m2 in i]: #if there are not already two pairs, and if the client has not already been added, append the pair to the list
        d.get(m).append((c,m))
    else:
        pass

ndf = pd.merge(df,pd.DataFrame([k for v in d.values() for k in v],columns = ['Client','Manager'])).sort_values('Client') #filter for just the pairs found above.
```

Output:

```
   index  Client  Manager  Score
3      0       1        1   0.89
1      5       2        3   0.97
5      7       3        2   0.61
2     11       4        3   0.93
4     12       5        1   0.78
0     16       6        2   0.99
```